# how to iterate over all files in path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate over all the text files in a specific path as so:

```
path = "c:\\Python27\\test"

with open(path+'\\*.txt') as fin:
print 'test'
```

but this returns:

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Python27\\test\\*.txt'
```

Why is that so? and what is a simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple ways might be:

```
import os
path = "c:\\Python27\\test"

for name in os.listdir(path):
    if name.endswith('.txt'):
        fpath = os.path.join(path, name)
        with open(fpath) as fin:
            print fpath, 'opened'
```

or

```
import glob
path = "c:\\Python27\\test"

for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    with open(fpath) as fin:
        print fpath, 'opened'
```

The reason is that `open()` must get a valid file name. The `*` stuff is syntactic sugar which must be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("c:\\Python27\\test"):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
          print 'test'
```